# Using `disable_functions` on php.ini per directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know I can only set `disable_functions` on `php.ini`. It works fine.

But I would like to override the default `disable_functions` per directory (inside `php.ini` file).

I cant make it work! I am following everything says at the documentation but it still does not work.

My `php.ini` looks like this:

```
disable_functions = "phpinfo"

<Directory /ebs1/apache/www/html/temp/>
    disable_functions "exec"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I call a script inside `/ebs1/apache/www/html/temp/` that contains only `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` I still get an error saying that `phpinfo` was disabled.

So how do I override this configuration inside the `php.ini` per directory?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php only changeable in system wide php.ini, NOT per directory

Comment: @tim The link you provided says that it can only be seted on PHP_INI_SYSTEM. But it does not say anything regarding it cant be set per directory/virtual host.

Comment: i read it as that's exactly what it is saying, and your own experience seems to agree